# Unable to download an iOS app from iTunes Japan when I am using my Apple account registered in the USA

Tags: ios, itunes-store, internationalization

I'm trying to download the [Denwacho Kantan Copy](http://mb.softbank.jp/mb/iphone_en/pdc/) app for iOS so that I can transfer my contacts to my new softbank iPhone.  However, I am being told that I can't download this app with my American Apple ID account.  I have downloaded countless apps in Japan without having this problem.  Please help!  Kantan means easy in Japanese and this has been anything but easy.  I have already tried changing my apple ID to a Japanese one, but this cannot be done without a Japanese credit card...which is very difficult to acquire here for foreigners.  If I was able to purchase this phone using the security of my American credit card, why shouldn't I be able to do something simple like transfer my contacts?? Everything else works fine!

Answer (score 1):

You can try following [this procedure](http://youtu.be/LuGseTGFJdo) (Youtube Video) to create an Apple ID in iTunes without a Credit Card, substituting US for Japan.

You need to follow these steps to create an Apple ID with a U.S. address but without requiring a credit card:

1. Launch iTunes and switch to the iTunes store. Make sure you are not
   logged in.
2. Scroll to the bottom and change your country to United States.
3. Next go to App store and download any of the free apps.

iTunes will now prompt you to create a new Apple account and this time, you’ll definitely see the ‘none’ option on the Payments screen.

[Source](http://www.labnol.org/software/apple-id-without-credit-card/19299/).

Comment: This does void the terms of service and can get one or all of your accounts permanently disabled, then you'll lose access to update all apps, purchased or not.

Comment: There's nothing voiding any terms of any service. This is a normal workflow of the iTunes app.